# anonymous/ nameless array in JS

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

```
export default [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bertie Yates',
    age: 29,
    image:
      'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-2_ipcjws.jpg',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Hester Hogan',
    age: 32,
    image:
      'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-3_rxtqvi.jpg',
  }
];
```

i just dont understand this piece of code works in JS, its possible to create array or object without assigning it to a variable and then access its value from somewhere else?

Comment: It's the `default` thing that gets `export`ed from this module, and you can import it in another module under any name you want.

Comment: It actually does create a (hidden, inaccessible) variable, export that and, assign the value to it. `export default …` is equivalent to `let __default = …; export { __default as default }`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. :-)

You are defining the content of your array in this file (let us call it `my-array.js`

Now you can access it from another file via require (or import). But when you do that, you have to give it a name.

`const myArray = require('my-array.js')`

As a result then "myArray" is the array that you have defined in `my-array.js`.

So, yes you define the array without giving it a name. But this task needs to be done then elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's named and default exports in JS. Here's 4 files to highlight the mechanics.

namedimport.js

```
function add(a, d) { 
  return a + b; 
} 
function mult(a, b) { 
  return a * b; 
} 
export { add, mult};
```

example1.js

```
import { add, mult } from './namedimport; 
console.log(add(1, 2))  
console.log(mult(2,3))
```

defaultimport.js

```
var a=5;  
export default a;
```

example2.js

```
import b from './defaultimport';  
console.log(b); // this will show up 5 as b refers to the default export (which was a)
```

This shows how you can import the default export in your JS with any name.